# How can I use min function with @hybrid_method?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to return the result of a `hybrid_method` from my query:

```
session.query(Table1.weight_time(date, Table2.daily_weight))
```

Where `date` is a `datetime` object and `Table2.daily_weight` is the following:

```
@hybrid_method
def weight_time(self, curr_match_date, daily_weight):
    no_days = curr_match_date - self.date_time_inferred
    return min(daily_weight ** no_days, daily_weight)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
Boolean value of this clause is not defined
```

If I strip off `min()` then I get another error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'InstrumentedAttribute' and 'BinaryExpression'
```

I'm clearly trying to get two objects to interact that don't like each other :)

I've tried changing the query to:

```
session.query(Table1.weight_time(date, 2))
```

But I still get the same errors as before.

How could I solve this?

Comment: @Carcigenicate - yep understand that. I just don't know how to convert them to the right type!

Comment: It looks like you are passing model column attributes, rather than values, to the method?

Comment: @snakecharmerb - hey! I'm trying to return the result of the `hybrid_method` from my query. So something like `qry = session.query(Table.weight_time(curr_match_date)` where `curr_match_date` is a `datetime` object

Comment: Actually - hang on. Getting myself confused. Let me check something

Comment: Original error wasn't correct! Updated